# How to run a function when page is activated in intel xdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, intel-xdk

I have a page `#list_menu` for example and I wanna run a function when the page loaded or activated I use

```
$("#list_menu").load(function(){run sth})
```

But it isn't work do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Any error in your console?

Comment: No error in console 

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is sent by elements associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

You can do something like this, to be sure your element exists :

```
if( $('#list_menu').length ){
    // your function
}
```

Or when the window is loaded :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // your function
});
```

Comment: It isn't work the page in intel xdk it isn't page like web site pages they are a div with id and you use activate_page(pagename) then it send you to the div  all design of Cordova app is one html file that consists all mobile app pages